# How to interpolate java expressions in struts attribute strings

Tags: java, jsp, struts, taglib

I have the following:

`<html:select property="myMap(abc)">`

What I really need to do, however, is pull the string `abc` from a static  member of a java class.

I thought something like

`<html:select property="myMap(<%=MyClass.FIELD%>)">`
, but that didn't work.

What's the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<% String name = "myMap(" + MyClass.FIELD + ")"; %>
<html:select property="<%=name%>">
```

Comment: Oh, duh! You can just inline the whole addition, and you're good.